# Theme Specific Applications only (In Special Banshee)

Tags: themes, banshee

There. I have made a custom version of the Ambience Theme, that is in a light green color.

Now, I want to darken up the banshee player a bit, that it doesn't blind me at night. I found a file called banshee.rc in the gtk-2.0/apps folder of the theme. Is it possible to change the look of banshee with this file? Where do I find some documentation about that type of styling files?

Comment: by the way: I am using ubuntu 14.04 Unity.